# Templates in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a template in Eclipse that eveytime I open a new file it opens it with:

```
'''
Created ${date}

'''
${cursor}
```

This works however the date looks like:

```
Created 20 באוג 2015
```

How do I change it to:

```
Created 20 Aug 2015
```

For some reason it takes the month in [Hebrew letters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_alphabet) rather than in English.

**Edit:** format of `DD/MM/YYYY` is also ok. It has no letters so it would work on any language what so ever.
I tried : `Created  ${id:date('dd MM YYYY')}`
But it also generates:

```
Created 20 באוג 2015
```

Answer (score 4):

Eclipse is using your System-Locale (i guess that is Hebrew?). There is currently no way to change that. There is a Bug open, to change that behavior: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=75981

---

I found a workaround, if you change the locale of the JVM, you can have a different locale and therefore a differnet Date-String, but only the default Date Strings for each language:

Edit your eclipse.ini and add the line (after `-vmargs`)

```
-Duser.language=en 
-Duser.country=US
```

With that you can use the en_US Locale.

To see, how each Dateformat in the different Locales look, use this code:

```
Locale[] availableLocales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
for (Locale locale : availableLocales) {
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    System.out.printf("%5s - %s %n" , locale.toString() ,SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance().format(new Date()));
}
```

`SimpleDateFormat.getDateInstance()` is what Eclipse uses to format the `${date}` Tags.

Comment: My opearating system is in English. If not possible is there a way to change it to `'DD/MM/YYYY'` that would be ok too and has no letters in it so should work for any language.

Comment: It seems there is no other way. Vote for that Bug, according to the comments they have a solution but its not integrated jet (i tried with Eclipse 4.4.2 and 4.5.0).

Answer (score 4):

Now that I have fixed [Bug 75981](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=75981) with Eclipse Neon M5, the syntax you have described just works:

```
Created  ${id:date('dd MM YYYY')}
```

You can download it with the Neon M5 Milestone Release here:

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php

… or wait until June 2016 for the official Neon Release.

Following is possible:

- No arguments, Example: `${date}` (as before)
- You can use the variable with additional arguments:

  - The first parameter is the date format. Example: `${d:date('yyyy-MM-dd')}`
  - The second parameter is the locale. Example: `${someDate:date('EEEE dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z', 'fr')}`

Here a screenshot of the Eclopse Preferences Page:

[image: Edit Template in Eclipse Preferences]

See also my blog post: [Bug 75981 is fixed!](http://jmini.github.io/blog/2016/2016-02-06_bug-75981-is-fixed.html)